# Ignore SSL certificate works with Maven 3 but fails for Maven 2 with SSL Socket Factory Exception

Tags: maven, ssl

When using IBM JDK, "Cannot find the specified class `com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory` can be bypassed by commenting 2 lines in java.security file

I also found out the running Maven with `"-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true"` will skip the SSL check and this solution works for me in Maven 3 (3.3.9), but the same approach fails with SSLSocketFactory Exception in Maven 2 (2.2.1)

So, I was wondering

1. Whether there is any other possibility in Maven 2 to get around the `SSL Exception`(other than commenting 2 lines in java.security file) and
2. Why `"-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true"` worked for Maven 3 while
   the same failed for Maven 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the way to resolve this issue.
The resolution is given in IBM site itself. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_trouble.html#rwlp_trouble__ssl01

1. Create a file called my.java.security and add the following lines inside it.

> ssl.SocketFactory.provider=
>
> ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=

2. Add this line as one of the parameters to your maven command

> -Djava.security.properties=fullPathTo/my.java.security

For example:

```
mvn clean install -Djava.security.properties=fullPathTo/my.java.security
```

This worked for me :)

In this way, you are not editing the default java.security file shipped with IBM JDK, but I'm still confused as to why `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true` didn't work for Maven 2.